# Is it possible to shrink DMG images?

Tags: macos, dmg-image

I just did some data recovery on a failing hard drive. I have a 1.5 TiB DMG image of the hard drive. I don't have enough free space to simply copy the files elsewhere, and I would like to extract them in place.

How can I move the files out of the image? I just moved some files with Finder but the size of the DMG file doesn't seem to have changed. Can I shrink a the partition inside the DMG  file in order to reclaim some space?

Comment: you could create a `7z` archive of the `DMG` image. That would likely shrink down the file size provided it is not encrypted or something.

Comment: @kush have you tested that ? I just tested on a small image I created, but the blocks are still there after a deletion, hence compression has no effect.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4913773/compression-method-for-dmg) question suggests you are correct.

Answer (score 3):

I have been able to successfully reduce the size of a DMG image after it was originally created using the `hdiutil resize` command.

```
hdiutil resize -sectors min image.dmg
```

I believe it depends on how the DMG image was initially created.

Comment: Thanks dedmonds, it's not perfect but I have managed to free up a considerable space with your answer

Answer (score 0):

In general, you can't shrink images once they're created. It's also exceedingly difficult to grow them (disk images). The best way to save space is to try to compress the image, but that may make extraction more difficult.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a DMG image you can create it using a compressed format. Once it exists however, then you either have to create a new one & transfer all the data to it, or simply compress it another way eg by turning it into a zip file.